# SSC-32, can I and how can i program it

Tags: microcontroller, servo

A friend recently gave me [this](http://www.lynxmotion.com/p-395-ssc-32-servo-controller.aspx) board that he had never used and didn't know anything about it. It had a USB to serial cable plugged into it with the driver software that I installed and it had a servo motor included. Question 1- is this a micro controller (i know it has something to do with servo motors but is it programmable?)? Question 2- if this is programmable how can i program it (what language, what tools) and if so can i UNPLUG it from the computer and still have it run (flash memory or something like that) And last, does this have inputs (digital, analog) so I can perform actions based on the inputs? i notice some pins in the middle that don't look like they are for servos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSC-32 is a dedicated servomotor controller with an embedded microcontroller in it, the [ATmega168](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf).

Answer 1: It *has* a microcontroller, and thus *is* a microcontroller board.

The microcontroller on this can be reprogrammed - ICSP pins are accessible on the board, though not in a convenient ICSP header. However, it comes preprogrammed with serial interface and servo control logic, changing the programming will eliminate the purpose of this board.

Answer 2: You can program it in C using AVR-GCC, or any of a host of other programming tools that support Atmel ATmega microcontrollers. You will also require a programmer device, one that supports ICSP.

Yes, the board can operate when unplugged from the computer, so long as an appropriate power source is provided to it. The microcontroller internally contains Flash memory, as well as RAM and EEPROM storage. See the datasheet linked above for details.

Last: The microcontroller does have both analog and digital input/output pins, but they may not all be conveniently broken out to pins on the board. So yes, if you sacrifice the Servo Controller function of the board, you can use it to perform actions based on inputs.

Those pins you notice in the middle are, in fact, input pins used by the default programming to trigger servo related functions.

Comment: But can I program it with its serial interface?

Comment: The serial interface is for sending commands as defined in the servo controller manual - not for programming.

Comment: You might be able to flash an Arduino bootloader and use it as such, the ATmega168 is certainly up to job. You'll most probably need a high voltage programmer, but that sounds more complicated than it really is.

Comment: @jippie If OP has the programmer and toolchain for HV programming, or for ICSP bootloader installation, then they _already_ have the capability to program the device, so the query is _already_ suitably resolved at that stage.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is a shameless plug for a friend/former employer.

As Anindo points out, you can't reprogram the SSC-32 without wiping its normal servo controller functionality. If you program it with the ISCP header, it's just an ATMega168 board with headers broken out for servo hookups, but you've deleted the servo control code. However, the [Servotor32](http://arcbotics.com/products/servotor32/) is designed to do exactly that. The onboard microcontroller is an ATMega32U4 running the Arduino Leonardo bootloader.

It uses a bunch of CPU time (and the SPI bus) for the servo control portion, but most of the spare I/O is broken out and you can write code in the normal Arduino IDE that works alongside the servo control library.

Both the SSC-32 and Servotor32 primarily function by accepting commands over a serial UART (USB as well for the Servotor32 instead of the big old DB-9 connector). The Servotor32 UART is broken out on the I/O header and can be used with an external Bluetooth module (sold separately).

Answer (score 0):

The board is a servo controller based on the  Atmel ATMEGA168. Tools and the relevant documents are available [here](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega168.aspx).

The board itself has [documentation](http://www.lynxmotion.com/images/html/build136.htm)

I don't see any ADCs or anything else. Look at the manual about whether it is USB powered or if it can be powered otherwise (it should be).

Comment: But I can still program it with only it's serial interface?